# No qualifying bean of type [...] found for dependency [...]: expected at least 1 or……

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mybatis

I was doing the project when you encounter a problem in the platform to find a solution can not be resolved, I would like to use MapperScannerConfigurer, to automatically scan my Dao layer files, but failed, the following is my code and error messages

Configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="City" type="org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.model.City" />
</typeAliases>
```

City.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao.CityDao">
<select id="getCityFromName" parameterType="string" resultType="City">
    select* from citys where city_name = #{city_name}
</select>
<select id="selectCitys" parameterType="string" resultMap="cityList">
    select * from citys where city_province = #{province}
</select>

<insert id="addCity" parameterType="City"  useGeneratedKeys="true"     keyProperty="id">
    insert into citys values(2333333,#{city_code},#{city_name},#{city_name_eg},#{city_province})
</insert>

<resultMap type="City" id="cityList">
    <id column="city_id" property="city_id" />
    <result column="city_code" property="city_code" />
    <result column="city_name" property="city_name" />
    <result column="city_name_eg" property="city_name_eg" />
    <result column="city_province" property="city_province" />
</resultMap>
</mapper>
```

CityDao.java file

```
public interface CityDao {

public City getCityFromName(String city_name);

public List<City> selectCitys(String province);

public void addCity(City city);
}
```

CityController.java

```
@Controller
public class CityController {
@Autowired
CityDao cityDao;

@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listAllCitys(ModelMap model){
    List<City> citys=cityDao.selectCitys("广东");
    model.addAttribute("citys",citys);
    return new ModelAndView("carlist","citys",citys);
}
}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="false">

<context:annotation-config />
<!-- 自动装配一定要 加上此片段 -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather_db?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory"  class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="Configuration.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations"
        value="classpath*:org/zhangzx/mybatis/demo/mapper/*.xml" />

</bean> 
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

the error meaasge

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cityController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cityDao': No qualifying bean of type [org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao.CityDao] found for dependency [org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao.CityDao]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao.CityDao] found for dependency [org.zhangzx.mybatis.demo.dao.CityDao]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: Do you have any class that Implements CityDao and do you have any spring bean of this class?

Comment: Could you share more stack trace ?